# Where is the logic for handling Unicode implemented?

Tags: unicode

I have found a corner case where the Unicode system dealing with the Tibetan language is fundamentally flawed. Rather than submitting a ticket, I would really want to learn how Unicode works and see if I can work out a solution myself. I think that would be much better to try to find a solution to the problem and submit that instead of just pointing out a flaw and demanding it to be fixed.

I am reading through the documentation I can find on the official web page and on the ICU web page. The more I read, the more questions come up.

The most pressing question to me is where I can find that logic that handles how multiple characters are rendered into a single glyph.

For instance: the character U+0f62 renders as ར (ra), but when coupled with the character U+0f99 (subjoined nya), it becomes རྙ. This is actually an exception to the rule, because if coupled with any other valid character, for instance U+0f97 ཇ (subjoined ja), the ra character changes the glyph to རྗ.
The font used to render the characters might be a bit small to see, but you can increase the font size of your browser to have a better look. Basically, the first case leaves the ra character almost identical to its common form when the nya character is subjoined to it. In most cases, the ra character whill change into a 'T' shape when another character is subjoined to it.

I would like to know where this logic is implemented, so I can start hacking on it and educate myself on this technology.

Any other recommendations of books and articles are also very appreciated.

Edit: I have been able to do some more tests and reading up on the Unicode specifications. My initial claims are invalid, since Unicode does take account for Tibetan transliteration of Sanskrit. Even highly compounded glyphs. It seems like the logic I am looking for is embedded into the fonts. Thanks to everybody who helped me in my search for knowledge.

Comment: On my machine (OS X) it appears very much the way you describe it; roundish together with *nya* but T-shaped together with *ja*. See http://imgur.com/FLHjzAs. If your system does not render it correctly, that's a fault in its font and/or font-rendering engine. Unicode "the standard" has little to do with that.

Comment: OK, so Unicode is just a standard. But I would really want to learn what technology I can hack if I want to modify the logic that determines the behavior I have described in the provided example.

Comment: The glyph shapes are described in the *font* being used, responsible for putting those shapes up on the screen is an appropriate *font rendering engine*. This is typically deeply integrated into the OS and hardly hackable. Of course, each application may choose to pack its own font rending engine, not using the OS' integrated one. I can't really tell you which piece is more likely to be responsible for this particular problem, the font or the renderer. I'd start by playing around with the font file, as that's simpler.

Comment: "Fundamentally flawed" as in "there is this one glyph which doesn't look like I would expect it to", or do you have more examples?

Comment: @tripleee No, no. This is not an example of what is flawed with the Unicode. This is just an example of what I want to understand about Unicode. The part that is flawed is quite advanced. It deals with the inability to correctly render glyphs of Sanskrit transliterated into Tibetan.

Comment: @deceze Is ICU a rendering engine?

Comment: No, ICU is a library for handling internationalization etc. On Linux, maybe look at Xft2 and/or Cairo. (Not technologies I know a lot about, just good Google hits.)

Comment: Actually, [Pango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pango).

Comment: Unicode does not deal directly with the rendering of glyphs; it deals with accurately recording the different characters.  Rendition is a problem for the software using Unicode — not a problem in Unicode itself.  See Chapter 1 of the Unicode standard (section 1.2 Design Goals) for a further discussion of this.